# React native nested navigation- getting navigation context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, nested, react-navigation

I am trying to build a simple nested navigator, a tab nav within a stack nav. I am getting:

> "undefined is not an object- evaluating this.props.navigation"

when trying to navigate stack via `"myFunction"` below. I tried another approach, which is to implement the stack navigation via the "headerright" of the navigation options- and it works. But I would really like to achieve it via a button in the contents portion. Code is below, with both navigation methods shown:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {
      AppRegistry,
      Text, View, Button, Image,  StyleSheet
    } from 'react-native';
    import { TabNavigator, StackNavigator } from "react-navigation";

    class RecentChatsScreen extends React.Component {

       static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: `Recent Chats`,
        headerRight: <Button title="Go Chat" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Chat', { user: 'Lucy' })}/>,
      });

    myFunction() {
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        navigate('Chat', { user: 'Lucy' });
    }

      render() {

        return (
        <View>
        <Text>List of recent chats</Text>
         <Button
              onPress={        
    this.myFunction
    }
              title="Go Chat."
            />
            </View>
            );
      }
    }

    class ChatScreen extends React.Component {
       static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'chat screen',
      };

      render() {
        return <Text>Chat screen</Text>
      }
    }

    class AllContactsScreen extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return <Text>List of all contacts</Text>
      }
    }

    const MainScreenNavigator = TabNavigator({
      Recent: { screen: RecentChatsScreen },
      All: { screen: AllContactsScreen },
    });

    MainScreenNavigator.navigationOptions = {
      title: 'My Chats',
    };

    const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
      Home: { screen: MainScreenNavigator },
      Chat: { screen: ChatScreen },
    });

    AppRegistry.registerComponent('SimpleApp', () => SimpleApp);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably forgot to *bind `this`*, so when calling `myFunction` its not inside class `RecentChatsScreen` scope.

Try add this

```js
class RecentChatsScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.myFunction = this.myFunction.bind(this);
    }
}
```